# Attempting to configure a generic component with react hook form

Tags: typescript, react-native, generics, react-hook-form

i created a generic radio button that works fine. Now i'm attempting to do some validation and going with react hook form. I went through the docs and a few tutorials but i'm running into an issue where typescript yells at me. When i do away with generics it works fine. What i'm doing wrong. Will appreciate some assistance or guidance.

```
export interface RadioButtonProp<T> {
    data: T[]
    value?: T
    render: (item: T, index?: number) => ReactNode
}

export const RadioButton = <T,>(props: RadioButtonProp<T>) => {
    const { data, render } = props
    return (
        <Container>
            {data.map((item: T, index: number) => {
                return <RowContainer key={index.toString()}>{render(item, index)}</RowContainer>
            })}
        </Container>
    )
}

const Container = styled.View`
    margin-top: 5px;
`

const RowContainer = styled.View``
```

Wrap around the controller to be used with react hook form:

```
export type RfhBadioButtonProp<T extends FieldValues> = RadioButtonProp<T> & UseControllerProps<T>

export const RhfRadioButton = <T extends FieldValues>(props: RfhBadioButtonProp<T>) => {
    return (
        <Controller
            rules={props.rules}
            control={props.control}
            name={props.name}
            render={({ field }) => (
                <>
                    <RadioButton
                        data={props.data}
                        render={props.render}
                        value={props.value || field.value}
                    />
                </>
            )}
        />
    )
}
```

In the form:

```
<RhfRadioButton
   control={control}
   name={'fruits'}
   data={['Apple', 'Oranges', 'Banana']}
   render={renderRadioButtons}
   value={fruit}
/>
```

Typescript complains:

```
Type 'Control<Fruit, any>' is not assignable to type 'Control<FieldValues, any>'.
  The types of '_options.resolver' are incompatible between these types.
    Type 'Resolver<Fruit, any> | undefined' is not assignable to type 'Resolver<FieldValues, any> | undefined'.
      Type 'Resolver<Fruit, any>' is not assignable to type 'Resolver<FieldValues, any>'
```